# User Authentication in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, servicestack

I did not get the Authentication and Authorization concept in servicestack.
I have been watching pluralsight tutorial but still i am not getting the point about how we can authenticate the username and password from our existing sql server database.
For Example if we authenticate user in asp.net with SQL server. there we provide connectionstring and then we write queries behind the button but in service stack how the plugins will work without knowing connectionstring and how user can logged in.

**Please help me :(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unsure how ServiceStack Authentication works I recommend looking to see how some of the [Live Demos that use Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#live-demos) works:

### [Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos)

To illustrate Authentication integration with ServiceStack, see the authentication-enabled live demos below:

- [HttpBenchmarks Application](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks)

  - [Step-by-Step Authentication Guide](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#authentication)
  - Twitter, Facebook, Google, LinkedIn and Credentials Auth
- [AWS Auth](http://awsapps.servicestack.net/awsauth/)

  - Twitter, Facebook, GitHub, Google, Yahoo, LinkedIn, and Credentials Auth
- [MVC and WebForms Example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration)

  - Twitter, Facebook, GitHub, Google, Yahoo, LinkedIn, VK, Credentials and Windows Auth
- [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos#chat)

  - Twitter and GitHub OAuth
- [SocialBootstrap Api](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos#social-bootstrap-api)

  - Twitter, Facebook, Yahoo and Credentials Auth

> but in service stack how the plugins will work without knowing connectionstring and how user can logged in.

ServiceStack doesn't guess, if you're using an [RDBMS backend data store](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#userauth-persistence---the-iuserauthrepository) you'll need to tell ServiceStack by [registering an OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks/blob/master/README.md#usersessions-and-userauth-repositories) which you'll need to pass it the `IDbConnectionFactory` that's configured with the DB ConnectionString and DB Type you want to use, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    dbConnectionString, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider));

container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

//Create any UserAuth tables that are missing
container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

#### Authenticating with an existing Database

But if you want to authenticate with an existing Database you can't use ServiceStack's existing User Auth Repositories and will instead need to [implement a Custom Auth Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) implementing `TryAuthenticate()` to validate the userName and password against your database yourself.

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
        string userName, string password)
    {
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, 
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, 
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        //Fill IAuthSession with data you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        //...

        //Call base method to Save Session and fire Auth/Session callbacks:
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        //Alternatively avoid built-in behavior and explicitly save session with
        //authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        //return null;
    }
}
```